# SQL : Selecting first letters of rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to get queries of two table from its first letters.

from searching , i got the following query :

```
SELECT substr( latin_name, 1, 1 ) AS alpha
FROM singers
GROUP BY substr( latin_name, 1, 1 )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and now i need to mix it with another table named `groups`

how can i collect all first letters of two different tables by one query?

Comment: UNION ALL         ...........

Comment: Why do so many people keep tagging both `mysql` and `sql-server`? Does anybody even read the pop-ups for the tags they're choosing?

Comment: @AaronBertrand cuz most ppl who knows sql-server also know mysql, just tagging to find more result from more ppl. sry if it upsets you.

Comment: That's not how tagging is supposed to work. I bet Oracle and Postgres folks would have some idea about your question too. Probably some people who know JavaScript and R and C# too.

Comment: @user2077916 if you have an issue with your windows computer, you don't tag Apple cuz most ppl who knows apple also know windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT LOWER(LEFT(`latin_name`, 1))
FROM `singers`
UNION
SELECT LOWER(LEFT(`latin_name`, 1))
FROM `groups`
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: Corrected, thanks. I've always used it with parentheses, but this way's better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true again, official manual says: "The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal."

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION Statement therefore:

```
SELECT ... FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT ... FROM table2
```